# Data retrieval in J2EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I've worked on EJBs before and I used stateless/stateful session beans and JPA for data retrieval. I'm now wondering if there are any other standard way of retrieving data in ejbs? (Except JDBC). Could some one guide me.

Comment: What's the problem with using JPA? Btw, it would depend on _where_ you want to retrieve data from. Do you mean getting data from the database in any case or might there be different datasources like webservices, filesystem etc.

Comment: @Thomas nothing it works great and i'm in the new environment. I need options to get data from database ofcourse.

Comment: If JPA works for you (and I mean the JPA standard, you might still try different implementations like Hibernate, Eclipse Link etc.) and you're working on a database that supports JPA (relational or object database) I'd just use that. JPA is an industry standard, has a big supporting community and lots of resources on the net, so unless you have _really_ good reasons to look for alternative, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Java Data Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects). It is standardized and can be used in the context of Java EE transaction services.